# Fetch value of 2nd Last List Item Jsoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I have **HTML code** as follows

```
<div id="wishlistPagination" class="a-container">
<span class="a-declarative" data-action="ajax-pagination" data-ajax-pagination="{}">
    <div class="a-text-center">
        <ul class="a-pagination">
            <li class="a-disabled">&larr;
                <span class="a-letter-space"></span>
                <span class="a-letter-space"></span>Previous
            </li>
            <li data-action="pag-trigger" data-pag-trigger="{&quot;page&quot;:1}" class="a-selected">
                <a href="/gp/registry/wishlist/3C96S5RO2A5A9/ref=cm_wl_sortbar_v_page_1">1</a>
            </li>
            <li data-action="pag-trigger" data-pag-trigger="{&quot;page&quot;:2}" class="a-">
                <a href="/gp/registry/wishlist/3C96S5RO2A5A9/ref=cm_wl_sortbar_v_page_2?ie=UTF8&page=2">2</a>
            </li>
            <li data-action="pag-trigger" data-pag-trigger="{&quot;page&quot;:3}" class="a-">
                <a href="/gp/registry/wishlist/3C96S5RO2A5A9/ref=cm_wl_sortbar_v_page_3?ie=UTF8&page=3">3</a>
            </li>
            <li data-action="pag-trigger" data-pag-trigger="{&quot;page&quot;:4}" class="a-">
                <a href="/gp/registry/wishlist/3C96S5RO2A5A9/ref=cm_wl_sortbar_v_page_4?ie=UTF8&page=4">4</a>
            </li>
            <li data-action="pag-trigger" data-pag-trigger="{&quot;page&quot;:5}" class="a-">
                <a href="/gp/registry/wishlist/3C96S5RO2A5A9/ref=cm_wl_sortbar_v_page_5?ie=UTF8&page=5">5</a>
            </li>
            <li data-action="pag-trigger" data-pag-trigger="{&quot;page&quot;:6}" class="a-">
                <a href="/gp/registry/wishlist/3C96S5RO2A5A9/ref=cm_wl_sortbar_v_page_6?ie=UTF8&page=6">6</a>
            </li>
            <li data-action="pag-trigger" data-pag-trigger="{&quot;page&quot;:7}" class="a-">
                <a href="/gp/registry/wishlist/3C96S5RO2A5A9/ref=cm_wl_sortbar_v_page_7?ie=UTF8&page=7">7</a>
            </li>
            <li data-action="pag-trigger" data-pag-trigger="{&quot;page&quot;:&quot;&amp;hellip;&quot;}" class="a-disabled">&hellip;</li>
            <li data-action="pag-trigger" data-pag-trigger="{&quot;page&quot;:9}" class="a-">
                <a href="/gp/registry/wishlist/3C96S5RO2A5A9/ref=cm_wl_sortbar_v_page_9?ie=UTF8&page=9">9</a>
            </li>
            <li class="a-last">
                <a href="/gp/registry/wishlist/3C96S5RO2A5A9/ref=cm_wl_sortbar_v_page_2?ie=UTF8&page=2">Next
                    <span class="a-letter-space"></span>
                    <span class="a-letter-space"></span>&rarr;
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</span>
```

**Java Code**:

```
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.sample_url.com").timeout(10 * 1000).post();
  Elements pages = doc.select("li[class*=a-last]");
  System.out.println("Value of List Item"+pages.get(0).text());
```

In the above case the value i'm trying to fetch the value of the 2nd last "li" tag which is is "9" in this case but it is dynamic, In some cases it can be 100 also. Currently I'm able to fetch the value of the last "li" tag.

**Output**:

```
Next
```

**Desired Output**:

```
9
```

Can't understand how to fetch the desired value. Please help..

Comment: can you share your code block ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake..I have shared the java code.Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will work for you but you could make use of the [JSoup Elements last() method](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) :

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.sample_url.com").timeout(10 * 1000).post();
    Element lastPagTrigger = doc.select("li[data-action=pag-trigger]").last();
    System.out.println("Value of List Item" + lastPagTrigger.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumed `a-last` classed item is first, following code blocks get previous element sibling text.

```
Element page = doc.select("li[class*=a-last]").first();
System.out.println("Value of List Item : " + page.previousElementSibling().text());
```

Also Tom Mac's answer is clear enough to get directly exact last list element via its data attribute.